# Traveling only with German Blue Card wıthout Passport

Tags: schengen, germany, italy, blue-card

I am a Turkish citizen and am a holder of the EU Blue Card in Germany. I gave my passport to the UK Embassy in Germany for my visa application, so my passport is not with me for a few weeks, but I need to go to Italy. My question is that can I travel with my Blue card but without my passport inside of Europe?

Comment: How will you be travelling?